# getting three data points for a single line of data at a single xtick

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a line chart using a Dataframe. Upon doing so, I'm seeing three data points on the graph for a single line of data.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4.6), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
ax.plot(df[column], df['Value'])
```

When I use dataframe's Bar chart, I'm seeing  plot correctly.

```
df.plot(x=column, ax=ax, kind='bar')
```

How to rectify this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaWb9.png)

Comment: I don't know what `column` is, but I think `ax.plot(df[column].values, df['Value'].values)` should work properly. If you can produce a [mcve] (i.e. a minimal runnable code) one could construct a bug report out of this.

Comment: why not use `df.plot(x=column, ax=ax, kind='line')`?

Comment: @tmdavison pandas line plot does not support string values for xticks https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22334 that is the reason I use `pyplot`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I used **column** to refer any generic column. Now, coming to the issue at hand, it seems like a bug with `pyplot`. Could you please have a look at github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13905 and check if you can help me out?

Comment: I commented on github. In that test.txt file, you have a repeated value in the `GNRL_Scenario` column: `V2017AC`, which is why the line jumps back and forward

Comment: Yup, thank you very much for pointing that out! My bad!

Comment: @tmdavison In that case, why pandas plot does not include two `V2017AC'?

Comment: I *think* pandas treats each value in the x data as a different index, even if repeated, while matplotlib will group repeated values together. But I'm not hugely familiar with pandas, so someone else can probably explain better.

Comment: You could be right, I used `drop_duplicates` method to drop the `V2017AC` duplicate and now things work fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the duplicate value in the 'GNRL_Scenario' column and plot the graph.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4.6), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   
df = df.drop_duplicates(df[column]) #for dropping duplicate values in this column
ax.plot(df[column], df['Value'])
```